# Android: disable content transition animation if API level is under 21

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, android-studio

I'm trying to follow the material design model by having the views which are shared between activities to animate to their new positions/attributes when going between activities.  I'm using the guide found at https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html.  However, these animations require API 21 and my app needs to reach a larger market share than that, so I want to only show the animations when the device has the appropriate API level.  How do I accomplish this?

Currently, I'm stuck at the first step.  When I add the line `<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>` to my style.xml, I get an error because my minimum API requirement is 11 (my target is 21).  The only solution I have found is to change the minimum API to 21.

P.S. I'm using Android Studio 1.0.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a new folder called `values-v21` in there you can add the line `<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>` to a separate `styles.xml` that will be used if the API level is 21+, then in your normal values or `values-v11` you don't include the line.